# Add to integers stored in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I stored two integers in two `LinkedList`,

- `LinkedList a` stores -49999
- `LinkedList b` stores 100001

How can I add the two integers together?

Comment: What have you tried? Which part of this is giving you trouble? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: And what does *large integer* means anyway. Those numbers are normal integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
long result = a.get(0) + b.get(0);
```

Then deal with `result`